# How do I iterate over a vocabulary list in Python?

Tags: python, list, numpy

Here's what I mean:
Say I have a list. Let's call it messages.

```
messages = ['hey how are you', 'doing good what about you']
```

My end goal is to run this list against another list of vocabulary, and if each word is in the vocab list, put it in another. This vocabulary list looks like this:

```
vocab = ['hey', 'how', 'you']
```

(Notice 'are' is omitted)
The final list of my formatted data right now looks like this:

```
final_list = np.array([['', '', '', ''], ['', '', '', '']])
```

I want it to look something like this:

```
final_list = np.array([['hey', 'how', 'you', ''], ['you', '', '', '']])
```

I have an idea using a `for` loop and `enumerate()`, but it's not working too well. Help would be appreciated!

Comment: Just to be clear, you *want* your final lists to have empty strings? and you want them at the *end* of the list regardless of where they appear in the original sentence?

Comment: Yep, the shape of the list is important. I don't want to have empty strings in the sequence of words, just at the end.

Comment: `[[i if i in vocab else "" for i in x.split()] for x in messages]` will get you close, but then you need to account for your 'push empty strings to end of list' criterion

Comment: In your example the second list has four elements ('you' plus three empty strings) but the second sentence has five words. So are the lists always four elements long regardless of how many words are in the original sentence?

Comment: Yep. So, if the sentence has more than four vocab words, it can just cut off any following that. It doesn't really matter how many words each message has, rather the sequence of vocabulary words, and keeping empty strings apart from the sequenced `['1', '2', '3', '' ]` idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go over the list of messages. For each message, split it into words, take at most N (N=4) words, and pad with empty strings, if needed.

```
N = 4
data = []
for m in messages:
    words = [x for x in m.split() if x in vocab]
    data.append(words[:N] + (N - len(words)) * [""])
final_list = np.array(data)
```

For better performance, convert `vocab` to a set before the loop:

```
vocab = set(vocab)
```

Result:

```
array([['hey', 'how', 'you', ''],
       ['you', '', '', '']], dtype='<U3')
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks so much! Could you explain the line with `words[:N] + (N - len(words)) * [""]`, or refer me to some documentation?

Comment: It is just what I said: take at most N words `words[:N]`, and pad `+` with empty strings, if needed `(N - len(words)) * [""]`. These are all basic Python operations.

Answer (score 1):

Try with two for loops:

```
vocab = ['hey', 'how', 'you']
messages = ['hey how are you', 'doing good what about you']
m = []
s = []
for x in messages:
  for y in x.split():
    if y in vocab:
      s.append(y)
  m.append(s)
  s = []
    
print(m)
```

To get empty elements:

```
vocab = ['hey', 'how', 'you']
messages = ['hey how are you', 'doing good what about you']
m = []
s = []
for x in messages:
  for y in x.split():
    if y in vocab:
      s.append(y)
    else:
      s.append('')
  m.append(s)
  s = []
    
print(m)
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer, but it's not exactly what I'm looking for. The shape of the final list is already defined, I don't want to be creating a new shape. Right now, I have `final_list = [['', '', '', ''], ['', '', '', '']]`, and I want to preserve the sequence of vocab words, with empty strings coming at the end, rather than interrupting the sequence.

Answer (score 0):

List comprehension is an efficient way to do this. You can then convert the output into an array if need be.

```
li = ['hey how are you', 'doing good what about you']
vocab = ['hey', 'how', 'you']

final_list = [[el if el in el2 else '' for el in vocab] for el2 in li]

print(final_list)
```

Output:

```
[['hey', 'how', 'you'], ['', '', 'you']]
```